# Filter out value from msg.payload in Node Red

Tags: filter, node-red

How could I filter out the camera resource **u'resource': u'cameras/52M18373B8573'** from the msg.payload. this is not a standard output and having "u" in front of the values makes it hard for me.

**msg.payload**

> motion event detected! {u'action': u'is', u'resource':
>   u'cameras/52M18373B8573', u'transId':
>   u'4RE3847UA0CBA!1b356cc9!1542454011169', u'from': u'4RE3847UA0CBA',
>   u'properties': {u'motionDetected': True}}

Comment: What is the source that this string has come from? It will be better to fix the source than filter this out later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u''` is the Python standard way of indicating a unicode string. So what you have is a Python dictionary. The app, which I guess is a python app, which generated the dictionary should have converted it into a JSON String using `json.dumps()` and sent the json, instead of sending the dict.